# vuejs not listening to onclick event on a button inside googlemap windowinfo

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I know this question has been asked [Click event inside GoogleMap InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913053/click-event-inside-googlemap-infowindow)
 but I did not find the answer helpful since I'm using **vuejs** and they were using plain js.

I am creating a **googlemap** with  customised parking places , I want when the user clicks on a parking place it should be able to display information about that parking slot and he can book it if he **clicks on book button** which is on the infowindow.

I am able to display the infowindow with the button on it but the click event does not work. I defined a method in vuejs called **submmitBooking**. How do I invoke that method?

Here is the code snippet.

```
 let content  = '<div class="table-responsive" >' +
                    '<table class="table">' +
                        '<tbody>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td>Parking Name:</td>' +
                                '<td>' + parking.name +'</td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td>Parking Type:</td>' +
                                '<td>'+ parking.zone + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td>Distance:</td>' +
                                '<td>'+ parking.distance + ' Kms away</td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td> 1.0 &euro;</td>' +
                                '<td> per hour</td>' +
                                '<td><button type="button" v-on:click="submitBooking(parking)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> Book </button></td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td>0.16 &euro;</td>' +
                                '<td>per 5mins</td>' +
                                '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" v-on:click="submitBooking(parking)" > Book </button></td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                        '</tbody>' +
                    '</table>' +
                '</div>'
let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:content,
    maxWidth: 350,
});


let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[1], latlng[0]),
    map: this.map,
    icon: icons.parking.icon,
    title: parking.name
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(content, 'click', function() {

});
```